# Flutter: how can upload pdf file to firebase storage?

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-storage, flutter-layout

I'm working on a Flutter app and i want upload PDF files to Firebase storage,
I pick file by using documents_picker but I cant upload it to storage ...please help me in this ...my code is below

```
uploaddoc()async{


   dynamic docPaths;
   // Platform messages may fail, so we use a try/catch PlatformException.
   try {
     docPaths = await DocumentsPicker.pickDocuments;
     final Directory tempDir = Directory.systemTemp;
     final String fileName = "${Random().nextInt(10000)}.pdf";
     final File file = File('${tempDir.path}/$fileName');
     file.writeAsBytesSync(docPaths);

     final StorageReference ref = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child(fileName);
     final StorageUploadTask task = ref.putFile(file);
     final Uri downloadUrl = (await task.future).downloadUrl;
     _path = downloadUrl.toString();

     print(_path);
   } on PlatformException {

   }

   // If the widget was removed from the tree while the asynchronous platform
   // message was in flight, we want to discard the reply rather than calling
   // setState to update our non-existent appearance.
   if (!mounted)
     return;

   setState(() {
     _platformVersion = docPaths.toString();
   });


  }
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use this dependency https://pub.dev/packages/file_picker to upload any kind of file to database.

```
final mainReference = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child('Database');
Future getPdfAndUpload()async{
  var rng = new Random();
  String randomName="";
  for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    print(rng.nextInt(100));
    randomName += rng.nextInt(100).toString();
  }
  File file = await FilePicker.getFile(type: FileType.CUSTOM, fileExtension: 'pdf');
  String fileName = '${randomName}.pdf';
  print(fileName);
  print('${file.readAsBytesSync()}');
  savePdf(file.readAsBytesSync(), fileName);
}

Future savePdf(List<int> asset, String name) async {

  StorageReference reference = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child(name);
  StorageUploadTask uploadTask = reference.putData(asset);
  String url = await (await uploadTask.onComplete).ref.getDownloadURL();
  print(url);
  documentFileUpload(url);
  return  url;
}
void documentFileUpload(String str) {

  var data = {
    "PDF": str,
  };
  mainReference.child("Documents").child('pdf').set(data).then((v) {
  });
}
```

By this you can upload file to firebase storage and insert the url to realtime database.